# Does this Fragment equal this Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I am updating an existing old app and trying to make it more Material and more up to date.

A key area of the old app had a 'wizard' type of interface which would be a chain of Activities where the user could add Parcelable data and move forwards and backwards through the wizard using either a UI back button or the Android back button.

I've updated to Fragments all over the app and, as Google say to not have a UI back button, I am relying on the default back button.

As the default back button doesn't register for Fragments, I am trying to implement something along the lines of the solution at [Vinsol](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/10/01/handling-back-button-press-inside-fragments/)

This kind of works, but I need to identify what Fragment used the back button so that I can decide what to do. This is the handler in the main Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(selectedFragment == null ) {
            //this isn't a Fragment we need to handle
            super.onBackPressed();
        }else if(selectedFragment == myFragmentOne){
            //do something here for that fragment
            //before going back
        }else if(selectedFragment == myFragmentTwo){
            //do something here for that fragment
            //before going back
        }
    }
```

The null handler works ok because I set selectedFragment to null on the Fragments I'm not interested in any special handling.

But selectedFragment is either null or a Fragment. How can I check if selectedFragment is myFragmentOne or myFragmentTwo? There are no Tags to check against.

Comment: Could this be an issue of `==` vs `.equals()`?

Comment: Use the FragmentManager's backstack.  Then, you can simply .popBackStack()  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()

Comment: I don't want to just pop the backstack though, I need to save and pass parcelable data to the receiving fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in this manner using `instanceOf`

```
if ( selectedFragment instanceof CustomFragmentClass) {
//put UR code
}
```